# Accessing NSMutableArray in class

Tags: iphone

In class1 I create an object of class2. I then use a method on this object to set its NSMutableArray

```
-(void) cloneArray: (NSMutableArray *) array{
    pictures = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array];
}
```

Class2 is a ViewController which has a UIImageView.

I present the class2 object after creating it. This class then has its own methods which display the next image when a swipe is detected.

```
-(void) nextImageSelector{
    if (counter == [pictures count]-1) {
    counter = 1; 
    asset = [pictures objectAtIndex:counter];
    ALAssetRepresentation *assetRepresentation = [asset defaultRepresentation];

    UIImage *fullScreenImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[assetRepresentation fullScreenImage] scale:[assetRepresentation scale] orientation:[assetRepresentation orientation]];

    photo.image = fullScreenImage;

    }
```

The app crashes when calling the line

> if (counter == [pictures count]-1)

So I think it is crashing because the array is created for an object and then the next array is trying to be checked is for the class instance itself.

How can I fix this so that I can copy an array for this class2 to use in its own methods like the nextImageSelector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think u are getting this problem because u are loosing the acces of the array try using, as it is accessor method.

```
-(void)cloneArray: (NSMutableArray *) array
{
    pictures = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array] retain];
}
```

Comment: That is exactly it, I never retained it, so I lost if when the function exited. Thanks a lot for this.   :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSZombiesEnabled` to find out if  your `NSMutableArray` gets deallocated. Have you checked your memory management? Run Build & Analyze could also help.

What kind of crash do you see?

In your `cloneArray` method the pictures array is not retained. You have to retain it in Class2 and make sure to release it once you are done with it in class 2's `dealloc` method.